need to render image on the left half of the screen in background
I'm not able to render the image fully on the screen in the left half of the screen, if it is fully rendered then the width is not full on the left half, or if the width is full then the height overflows.
It is a react app with tailwind css and material ui for styling.
 <div className="flex h-screen">
      <div
        className="w-1/2 h-screen bg-no-repeat bg-contain flex m-auto"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${signbg2})`,
        
        }}
      >
        <div className="h-screen m-auto text-white">
          <p>Solutions for the mining industry</p>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec
            vehicula luctus libero non eleifend. Vestibulum ante ipsum.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>Login form on the left</div>
<div>

current image in react app](https://i.sstatic.net/nTI5dxPN.png)
I expect the width to be exactly half of the left side of my screen such as the below
 similar expected one](https://i.sstatic.net/2uKoapM6.png)

In your left div change w-1/2 to flex-1
And in right div add flex-1
<div className="flex h-screen bg-cyan-500">
                <div
                    className="flex-1 h-screen bg-no-repeat bg-contain flex m-auto bg-slate-500"
                    style={{
                        backgroundImage: `url(${signbg2})`,
                    }}
                >
                    <div className="h-screen m-auto text-white">
                        <p>Solutions for the mining industry</p>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula luctus libero non
                            eleifend. Vestibulum ante ipsum.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="flex-1">Login form on the left</div>
            </div>

